# How to replace years without leading zeros, with leading zeros using Python re?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string containing date string, '363898,Catullus,84-11-1 BC' 
How can I replace year 84 with 0084 using Python re?

Comment: What kind of "date" is `363898,Catullus,84-11-1 BC`? What is the format it follows?

Comment: Before we invest effort in your question, show us what effort you've invested. What have you tried? What documentation have you read? Have you read the [Python re module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)?

Comment: Well I tried to match the year if it has only two digits followed by a comma (that is ,84 or ,76) with '\\,\d\d' , but the comma was not being escaped. I seem to miss a very trivial thing.

Comment: It's not a data, I'm guessing 363898 is an id, Catullus is a person who was probably born in 84BC, the month and day seem arbitrary and a rather strange choice. You need to format your data better and split it up into it's component parts.

Comment: @Sravan, you're escaping the slash with the `\\\`. Plus, you don't have to escape the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
import re
re.sub(r',(\d\d)-', r',00\1-', '363898, Catullus,84-11-1 BC')
```

With `r',(\d\d)-'` we capture any pair of digits (not less or more) that is between a comma and a dash. We replace the whole match with a comma, two zeros, whatever was between in the first pair of parenthesis (here the two digits), and a dash.

It means:

- if there are no two digits between a coma and a dash, no replacement is made. You get back your original string
- if there are these digits, there are replace by themselves, surounded by the same comma and dash, but with additional zeros.

When trying regular expressions in Python, just play with an [online regular expression tester](http://ksamuel.pythonanywhere.com/) Full disclaimer: I coded this one so I'm biased.

But maybe regular expressions are not the best fit for the job. Sometimes a good use of ordinary functions is just as good:

```
In [10]: entry = '363898,Catullus,84-11-1 BC'.split(',')
In [11]: numbers = entry[-1].split('-')
In [12]: numbers = '-'.join([numbers[0].zfill(4)] + numbers[1:])
In [13]: entry = entry = ','.join(entry[:-1] + [numbers])
In [14]: entry
Out[14]: '363898,Catullus,0084-11-1 BC'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, what modification has to be made to make years with single digit also to four digits like 8-11-1 to 0008-11-1?

Comment: With the non regex version, no modification. That's the point. With the regex version, you can find it easily: (\d\d) represent two digit. \d represent one digit. In the replacement pattern, \1 represent whatever is bein in parenthesis, the rest is constant. Play with value in the regex tester I gave you, you'll find your way.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: thanks for the edit. Years of practice but my english is still terrible. And I get corrected by a German guy :-D

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub(r"(?=\b\d{2}-\d+-\d)", "00", '363898,Catullus,84-11-1 BC')
```

will only modify years if they consist of exactly two digits. You'd need another

```
re.sub(r"(?=\b\d-\d+-\d)", "000", '361234,Caesar,8-12-4 BC')
```

to also handle single-digit years. I'll leave triple-digit years as an exercise :)